# Audio and video synchronization with OpenCV and ffpyplayer

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, opencv

I am currently working on a "game" that allows it user to shift the position of a circle while watching the video. The video shows two individuals, who each take turn to speak. The user's task is to change the position of the circle appearing to the active speaker. While this is occurring, at some point I plan to change the video without the user noticing while the "game" and circle continues to show.

To achieve this purpose, I wrote the following code. The code takes the input from the user, and sends all the data to a TCP server and prints the information to a logger file. But I run into an issue. Firstly, the audio and video is not synchronised and even using lowest value of `waitkey(1)`, audio is faster than the video

Any help on how to fix this issue will be highly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

PS- I am using Visual Studio code and my python version is 3.9.6 64-bit.

```
import cv2 as cv #import the OpenCV library
import numpy as np #Import Numpy Library
import socket  # socket creation for Telnet
from datetime import datetime
from telnetlib import Telnet #telnet client
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer #ffpyplayer for playing audio

current_date_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The remote host
PORT = 4212  # The same port as used by the server
TCP_PORT = 9999  # port used to connect with the server file

def send_data(message, s, output):
    s.sendall(message.encode())
    data = s.recv(1024)
    output.write('\n'+ current_date_time+' '+message+ '\n')
    return data

def circle(frame, left):
    if left:
        cv.circle(frame,(450,250),20,(255,255,255),50)
    if not left:
        cv.circle(frame,(1400,250),20,(255,255,255),50)

def video():
    cap1 = cv.VideoCapture('P1.mp4') # the video that we want
    player = MediaPlayer('P1.mp4')
    circle_is_left = True
    if (cap1.isOpened()== False):
        print("Error opening video 1")  
    while (cap1.isOpened()):
        ret,frame = cap1.read() #capture frame-by-frame video
        audio_frame,val=player.get_frame() # capture frame-by-frame audio
        if ret== True:
            key_pressed = cv.waitKey(1)
            if key_pressed == ord(' '): #pressing space bar ends the video
                with open('out.txt', 'a') as output:
                    send_data('video 1 is changed',s,output)
                break
            elif key_pressed == 2: #left key pressed changes circle to lett
                circle_is_left = True
                with open('out.txt', 'a') as output:
                    send_data('left',s,output)
            elif key_pressed == 3: # right key pressed changes circle to right
                circle_is_left = False
                with open('out.txt', 'a') as output:
                    send_data('Right ',s,output)
            circle(frame, circle_is_left) #display the circle at all times
            cv.imshow('cap1',frame) #display resulting frame 
            if val != 'eof' and audio_frame is not None:
                img,t = audio_frame
    cap1.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
 
    cap2 = cv.VideoCapture('P2.mov') # the video that we want
    player2 = MediaPlayer('P2.mov')
    circle_is_left = True
    if (cap2.isOpened()== False):
        print("Error opening video 2")  
    while (cap2.isOpened()):
        ret,frame = cap2.read() #capture frame-by-frame video
        audio_frame,val=player2.get_frame() # capture frame-by-frame audio
        if ret== True:
            key_pressed = cv.waitKey(1)
            if key_pressed == ord(' '): #pressing space bar ends the video
                with open('out.txt', 'a') as output:
                    send_data('video 1 is changed',s,output)
                break
            elif key_pressed == 2: #left key pressed changes circle to lett
                circle_is_left = True
                with open('out.txt', 'a') as output:
                    send_data('left',s,output)
            elif key_pressed == 3: # right key pressed changes circle to right
                circle_is_left = False
                with open('out.txt', 'a') as output:
                    send_data('Right ',s,output)
            circle(frame, circle_is_left) #display the circle at all times
            cv.imshow('cap2',frame) #display resulting frame 
            if val != 'eof' and audio_frame is not None:
                img,t = audio_frame
    cap2.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    print("Game1.py is connected to TCP server")
    video()
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, TCP_PORT))
    main()
```

Comment: it seems you run the same code for both `P1` and `P2` - so you could create function and run it with different filenames. For `P1` you use the same `P1.mp4` for cv and mediaplayer - but for `P2` you use different names `P2.mov` and `P2.mp4` - so maybe you run file with wrong audio.

Comment: @furas I did that and now video and audio at least break evenly. But I am still struggling to fix synchronisation issue.

Comment: `synchronisation` is big problem and I don't know solution for this. `MediaPlayer` runs external program which starts in different moment then `VideoCapture` and you can't control it. I would try to use some modules to access directly audio device - ie. [pyaudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/), [winsound](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html), [playsound](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/)

Comment: @furas since, the `MediaPlayer` is able to run the audio at the same fps as the original video(P1,P2) I want to keep it as it is. If there is a way to speed up `cv.VideoCapture` to make it (almost) the same as original video (P1,P2)

Comment: you can't speed up - you can only use `waitKey(millisecond)` to decide how fast it display.  Teoreticly if you set `waitKey(33)` then will run frame every `33ms` which gives `1000ms/33ms = 30 Frames Per Second` - but code runs also other functions which need time so you would have to measure time between frames and use corrected value in `waitKey`. And it `MediaPlayer` starts faster then `cv` then you could start `MediaPlayer` inside loop when you get first `cap1.read()` - maybe it will start almost in the same time.

Comment: @furas will putting `player.getframe()` after `waitKey` solve the issue of `MediaPlayer`  starting before `cv`. Also, since theoretically putting `waitKey(1)`  I get the max. possible fps (1000) and even that leaves video lagging behind audio=> increasing `waitKey` might slow video further down?

Comment: `1000 FPS` is only a theory. `waitKey(1)` waits at least 1ms but it may wait more - besides `read()` and other functions needs also some time - so finally you get much slower video. `waitKey` can reduce video speed when it is too fast but in your situations other code can slow you down - maybe you should `send_data` in separated thread. Or maybe you should open file only once because opening again and again also slow downs code.

Comment: @furas how do I achieve opening file only once and `send_data` is separate thread

Comment: you can put all `while`-loop in `while open('out.txt', 'a') as output`. OR before `while`-loop run `output = open('out.txt', 'a')` and before `cap1.release()` use `output.close()`. As for running `send_data` in thread it can be complex problem and better ask new question on new page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234936/discussion-between-tumul-kumar-and-furas).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` to synchronize video and audio as follows:

```
import cv2
import time
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer


def video(file):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
    player = MediaPlayer(file)
    start_time = time.time()

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        _, val = player.get_frame(show=False)
        if val == 'eof':
            break

        cv2.imshow(file, frame)

        elapsed = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000  # msec
        play_time = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))
        sleep = max(1, int(play_time - elapsed))
        if cv2.waitKey(sleep) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break

    player.close_player()
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

see https://github.com/otamajakusi/opencv_video_with_audio